# html table not getting updated when ng-repeat is updated

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I try to update the table by adding values through the form the scope variable gets updated but by table remains non updated. 
My table

```
<tbody> 
    <tr ng-repeat="ct in city">
        <td>
            <center>[ {{ct.location.latitude}} , {{ct.location.longitude}} ]</center>
        </td>
        <td>
            {{ct.name}} 
        </td>
```

my function to update list

```
window.siteadd = function(){
    var citlat = document.getElementById("citylat").value;
    var citlan = document.getElementById("citylon").value;
    var citname = document.getElementById("cityname").value;
    var citstat = document.getElementById("citynostation").value;
    var citytemp = {
        location:{
            latitude: citlat,
            longitude: citlan
        },
        name: citname,
    }
    console.log("temp", citytemp);
    $scope.city.push(citytemp);
    console.log("tempadded", $scope.city);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The table is not getting updated because the function `siteadd` is not running in context of angular and so a `$digest` cycle is not run by it for updating all the bindings in the view.

To make it possibe you have to call a `$digest` cycle explicitly in your function or just wrap the function inside `$scope.$apply`.

For your code:

```
window.siteadd = function(){
    var citlat = document.getElementById("citylat").value;
    var citlan = document.getElementById("citylon").value;
    var citname = document.getElementById("cityname").value;
    var citstat = document.getElementById("citynostation").value;
    var citytemp = {
        location:{
            latitude: citlat,
            longitude: citlan
        },
        name: citname,
    }
    console.log("temp", citytemp);
    $scope.city.push(citytemp);
    console.log("tempadded", $scope.city);
    $scope.$digest(); //just add this line and it will work.
}
```

/***** For your Information *****/

To better understand `$watch, $digest and $apply` please refer to the link
"http://angular-tips.com/blog/2013/08/watch-how-the-apply-runs-a-digest/"

Answer (score 0):

```js
var app=angular.module("app",[])


app.controller("itemController",function($scope){
  
 $scope.citytemp = {
        location:{
                    latitude: null,
                    longitude: null
                  },
        name: null
   }
 $scope.city=[];
   $scope.city.push($scope.citytemp);
  
});
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.16/angular.min.js"></script>  
</head>

<body ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="itemController">
   City Name: <input type='text' ng-model='citytemp.name'><br>
   Latitude: <input type='text' ng-model='citytemp.location.latitude'><br>
   Longitude: <input type='text' ng-model='citytemp.location.longitude'><br>
   
<table>
<tbody> 
    <tr ng-repeat="ct in city">
        <td>
          City Name: {{ct.name}} 
          <br> Location : [ {{ct.location.latitude}} ,{{ct.location.longitude}} ]           
        </td> 
        <td>
            
        </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```